# How to use single quotation in string manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can understand in the title, I want use single quotation in string manupulation. Here is my code:

```
 headline += '<article><h5><a class="headline" onmouseover="headLineDetail(' + this.HeadCaption + ',' + this.ShortDescription + ',' + this.PicUrl + ',' + this.NewsId + ')" href="NewsDetail.aspx?nid=' + this.NewsId + '"' + '">' + this.HeadCaption + this.time + '</a></h5>';
```

I have to give string parameters of headLineDetail with quotation. But I append headline to a div as inner html. How can I use single quotation in this case.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `\'` to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Just escape using a `\'`

```
headline += '<article><h5><a class="headline" onmouseover="headLineDetail(\'' + this.HeadCaption + '\',\'' + this.ShortDescription + '\',\'' + this.PicUrl + '\',\'' + this.NewsId + '\')" href="NewsDetail.aspx?nid=' + this.NewsId + '"' + '">' + this.HeadCaption + this.time + '</a></h5>';
```